# Pre-generated tiles don't works after Geoserver upgrading

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache, cache

I have upgraded Geoserver to the newest version (2.12.2), deployed old "data_dir" and set plugins respective to the version. After start Geoserver I tried to get pre-generated tiles via GeoWebcache but GWC don't see my cache and it starts seed new tiles.

This is my general GWC settings:

[image]

I just want to get my pre-generated map.

Did there anybody faced with such problem?

Comment: how did you deploy old data_dir? where is your cached data and where is geowebcache trying to create new tiles? what settings do you have on your GWC?

Comment: @Ian I did not removed new "data_dir", but replace it from old backup. Cached data store in the standard directory: data_dir/gwc/*layername*. GWC created tiles in the same folders.

Comment: did you restart geoserver after you "deployed" the old data dir?

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, I was restarting Geoserver after each change.

Comment: how old are your existing tiles?

Comment: @IanTurton A few months.